# MySQL UUID_SHORT data type

Tags: mysql

I have user table. The primary key is `user_id` which has a datatype `bigint(20)`.

I generate a `user_id` using `UUID_SHORT()` via trigger below. The issue is I get a warning when I try to insert a record as follows:

```
Warning: #1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'user_id' at row 1
```

My phpMyAdmin trigger is as follows:

```
BEGIN
SET NEW.user_id=UUID_SHORT();
END
```

Any reason why I am getting this warning? Have I set the datatype correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`INT` is a four-byte signed integer, while `UUID_SHORT()` returns a 64-bit (i.e. 8 byte) unsigned integer.  You are trying to store a 64-bit data type into a 4-byte `INT` and MySQL appears to be storing an empty string `''` into the field `user_id`.

From the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/miscellaneous-functions.html):

> UUID_SHORT()
>
> Returns a “short” universal identifier as a 64-bit unsigned integer (rather than a string-form 128-bit identifier as returned by the UUID() function).

You should use the `BIGINT UNSIGNED` type instead.

Comment: Thanks so what is the best datatype to choose for UUID_SHORT() fields?

Comment: Thanks I've changed to an unsigned. However I'm still getting the warning. I actually think it may be to do with the Trigger. As I am leaving the user_id empty it is trying to store '' into the field before the trigger is executed. Could this be right?

Answer (score 2):

will not work if you try to insert from PMA, as it generate this kind of query :

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`, `name`) VALUES ('', 'sami')
```

you can replace the '' with NULL, or remove user_id from the insert

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`name`) VALUES ('sami')
```

this will solve the warning problem.

Answer (score -1):

First you shoud change the datatable of the `BIGINT UNSIGNED` like suggested in [Tim Biegeleisens answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30181651/2377961).

And to set this id you check in your trigger, if the id col is empty

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS insert_user_uuid
BEFORE INSERT
ON user FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF NEW.user_id IS NULL OR NEW.user_id = '' THEN
      SET NEW.user_id = UUID_SHORT();
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```